# Stopping timer not working:

Tags: javascript, timer

I have [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/38th0zze/) timer in my project.
When it runs out, it shows a Time Up screen, which works fine.
But when the player is Game Over, i show the Game Over screen, but the timer keeps running and when it hits 00:00 then it switches to the Time Up screen.

How can i make this timer stop counting down and set to 00:00 again?

I tried adding a function like this:

```
CountDownTimer.prototype.stop = function() {
  diff = 0;
  this.running = false;    
};
```

I also tried to change the innerHTML but its obvious that its just changing the numbers without stopping the timer and after a second it will show the count down again... I don't know what to call.

```
//Crazy Timer function start
function CountDownTimer(duration, granularity) {
  this.duration = duration;
  this.granularity = granularity || 1000;
  this.tickFtns = [];
  this.running = false;
}

CountDownTimer.prototype.start = function() {
  if (this.running) {
    return;
  }
  this.running = true;
  var start = Date.now(),
      that = this,
      diff, obj;

  (function timer() {
    diff = that.duration - (((Date.now() - start) / 1000) | 0);

    if (diff > 0) {
      setTimeout(timer, that.granularity);
    } else {
      diff = 0;
      that.running = false;
    }

    obj = CountDownTimer.parse(diff);
    that.tickFtns.forEach(function(ftn) {
      ftn.call(this, obj.minutes, obj.seconds);
    }, that);
  }());
};

CountDownTimer.prototype.onTick = function(ftn) {
  if (typeof ftn === 'function') {
    this.tickFtns.push(ftn);
  }
  return this;
};

CountDownTimer.prototype.expired = function() {
  return !this.running;
};

CountDownTimer.parse = function(seconds) {
  return {
    'minutes': (seconds / 60) | 0,
    'seconds': (seconds % 60) | 0
  };
};

window.onload = function () {
    var display = document.querySelector('#countDown'),
        timer = new CountDownTimer(timerValue),
        timeObj = CountDownTimer.parse(timerValue);

    format(timeObj.minutes, timeObj.seconds);

    timer.onTick(format).onTick(checkTime);

    document.querySelector('#startBtn').addEventListener('click', function () {
        timer.start();
    });

    function format(minutes, seconds) {
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
        display.textContent = minutes + ':' + seconds;
    }

    function checkTime(){
    if(this.expired()) {
        timeUp();
        document.querySelector('#startBtn').addEventListener('click', function () {
        timer.start();
    });
    }
    }
};
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: When the timer's up, have you tried to check if the game was over before displaying the time up screen ?

Comment: `//Crazy Timer function end` how choice name! That's the root of the problem

Comment: I would suggest using `setInterval` to be able to cancel independent timers

Comment: i just updated the post. @Hero-Luin yes i tried to declare a variable called gameStop = 0; and then changed it with the gameOver function to 1 but in the timer function where i call the TimeUp(); function it didnt work by using an if statement.

Comment: Despite the title of the question you're missing anything that could be called _stopping the timer_ in your code... You should either change implementation of `CountDownTimer` or use @TomJenkins answer

Answer (score 2):

Instead of recursively calling `setTimeout`, try `setInterval` instead. You could then store a reference to the timer:

```
this.timer = setInterval(functionToRunAtInterval, this.granularity);
```

and kill it when the game finishes::

```
clearInterval(this.timer)
```

(see [MDN's docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) for more info on setInterval)

Comment: Thanks, how would i implement this into my code? sorry i'm only 3 weeks into my js class.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while and I'm not sure if you've figured it out but check out the fiddle below:
    https://jsfiddle.net/f8rh3u85/1/

```
// until running is set to false the timer will keep running
if (that.running) {
    if (diff > 0) {
      setTimeout(timer, that.granularity);
    } else {
      diff = 0;
      that.running = false;
    }

    obj = CountDownTimer.parse(diff);
    that.tickFtns.forEach(function(ftn) {
      ftn.call(this, obj.minutes, obj.seconds);
    }, that);
}
```

I've added a button that causes running to be set to false which stops the timer.

Button:

```
<button id="stop">Game Over</button>
```

Code:

```
$( "#stop" ).click(function() {
    timer.running = false;
});
```

So that should hopefully get you to where you need to be.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Tom Jenkins' answer, you need to cancel the next tick by avoiding the `diff > 0` branch of your if statement.  You could keep your code as it stands and use your suggested `stop` method, however, you'd need to change your logic around handling ticks to check that both `running === true` and a new param `gameOver === false`.

Ultimately, I think your problem is that no matter whether the timer is running or not, you'll always execute this code on a tick:

```
obj = CountDownTimer.parse(diff);
that.tickFtns.forEach(function(ftn) {
  ftn.call(this, obj.minutes, obj.seconds);
}, that);
```

If you have a game over state, you probably don't want to call the provided callbacks, so add some conditional check in there.